# How can I delete User Defaults for iOS app being developed on a Mac

Tags: ios, macos, userdefaults

I am developing an iOS app in Swift on a Mac running Catalina using Xcode and would like to clear User Defaults using `defaults delete bundleidentifier`. However, the command fails with 'Domain(bundleidentifier)  not found' because the file bundleidentifier.plist is not present in /Library/Preferences (as is the case for a MacOS app) or in the iOS simulator  Library/Preferences folder. Where are the user defaults stored in this case and how can I delete them?

Comment: It's in your app's _sandbox_.

Comment: The simplest way is to delete the app from the simulator.

Comment: Deleting the app does not remove the defaults from the cache - set values still appear after this.

Comment: @ArthurRees Please demonstrate how you know that. Without actual code for reproducing the problem you are having, the question is sort of pointless.

Answer (score 2):

Found the the bundleidentifier.plist file in `/users/<UserName/>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<DeviceCode>/Containers/Data/Application/<ApplicationCode>/Library/Preferences`.

`<DeviceCode>` is the code for the simulator being used and `<ApplicationCode>` is the code for application. These codes were found by looking at the DateModified values for all the DeviceCodes and ApplicationCodes. Deleting the file leaves the UserDefault values in the cache. Would be useful to find a way of clearing this without rebooting. `defaults delete bundleidentifier` on Mac does not seem to work when using an iOS simulator.

Comment: Is this the answer you were looking for?